# Can't redirect to search result page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm not good at English, so it might be hard to explain my intention.

I'm using React, React router, Apollo client,
In production build, When I click the search button, I can't redirect to render a result component because of error with error message
 error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

First, I tried without useEffect. It occur error as described above.

Second, I tried with useEffect hook, that change redirect state to false. and it changes url. but doesn't render result component.
useEffect(() => {setRedirect(false)}, [redirect])

Finally I tried to make another react app to test this situation without apollo, and some custom components that are for clean code in the production build. I tried in development build. And it perfectly works without error

```
// search-bar.js
function SearchBar(props) {
  // keywords for searching books
  const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState('');
  // search option
  const [option, setOption] = useState('All');
  // determine to redirect or not
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="nav-search">
        <form
          role="search"
          onSubmit={ e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setRedirect(true);
          }}
          className="form-search"
        >

          <NotRequiredInput
            type="search"
            label="Search keywords: "
            id="keywords"
            value={keywords}
            onChange={e => {
              setKeywords(e.target.value);
            }}
          />

          // it map the list's items to option
          <SelectBoxWithoutNone
            label="Search option: "
            id="search-option"
            value={option}
            onChange={e => {
              setOption(e.target.value);
            }}
            list={['All', 'Title', 'Author']}
          />

          <SubmitButton label="Search" />
        </form>
      </div>
      { redirect && <Redirect to={`/search?o=${option}&k=${keywords}`} /> }
    </>
  );
}

// app.js
<Query>
  {({loading, data}) => {
    if (loading)
    return (
      <Header>
      <NavBar>
      <main>
        <Suspense>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/search" render={props => <SearchResult {...props}/>}
    )
  }}
  // app.js looks like this with many route component.
  // also using React.lazy for code splitting

// search-result.js
function SearchResult (props) {
  const parsed = queryString.parse(props.location.search);
  const option = parsed.o;
  const keywords = parsed.k;

  return (
    <div className="div-search-result">
      <p>{option}</p>
      <p>{keywords}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I expected that it renders result component (with or without hooks)
but as I described above, It occurred error

Update: When I tried to type some query parameter on url path directly, it works.

Comment: Never mind. with useEffect, it works as I intended. But without useEffect hook why in production cause error, not in development?

Comment: I think without hooks this code might trigger infinite redirect, so occur error, but i'm not sure. and even though why it works in development build